# Tika Parser behaviour different in REPL and jar

Tags: clojure, jvm, dependency-management, leiningen, apache-tika

### Description

We use the [Tika Parser](https://tika.apache.org/1.27/index.html) in a wrapped version behind [pantomime](https://github.com/michaelklishin/pantomime) with no config (default), which uses the `AutoDetectParser`. It was essential to upgrade the Tika dependency due to missing functionality. After overwriting tika as a dependency of 1.27 along other dependencies, we observed some unexpected behaviour. While running the service in a `lein repl`, tika correctly converted the document in question (.doc).
Afterwards we packed the clj-code with `lein uberjar`.

Now the fun part began:
A wild bug hunt into the dep(th)s of tika and type casts followed.
**The issue was found to be a different parsed data type**. While in the REPL the parsed data type was a `javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage`, with the produced .jar the parsed data type was a `javax.mail.util.SharedByteArrayInputStream`.
A log excerpt:

#### REPL

```
[2021-10-08 16:56:30,406] TRACE xxx - Unpacking MimeMessage -1
[2021-10-08 16:56:30,407] DEBUG xxx - |> type javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage
[2021-10-08 16:56:30,415] DEBUG xxx - ||> javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@397fca9a
[2021-10-08 16:56:30,415] DEBUG xxx - |-> transforming multipart/mixed to Mime for instance javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart
```

#### jar

```
[2021-10-08 17:02:55,181] TRACE xxx - Unpacking MimeMessage -1
[2021-10-08 17:02:55,183] DEBUG xxx - |> type javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage
[2021-10-08 17:02:55,191] DEBUG xxx - ||> javax.mail.util.SharedByteArrayInputStream@b83be05
[2021-10-08 17:02:55,193] WARN xxx - Mime unpacking unsuccessful: multipart/mixed - javax.mail.util.SharedByteArrayInputStream
```

### Findings

I suspect that there might be a clash of dependencies, as both the tika-parser and the simplejavamail modules use an implementation of `MimeMessage`, which is provided by both `jakarta.mail` and `javax.mail`. I already resolved the dependency clashes hinted by leiningen, but suspect there might be something going on in how `lein repl` resolves dependencies, which makes it work in that case.
This behaviour was reproduced with a clean profiles.clj.
Logging and stacktrace hint to this function [.getContent](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/mail/1.6/apidocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getContent--), which is responsible for returning the appropriate Object.

#### project.clj

```clj
(defproject my-project :lein-v
  :plugins [[lein-parent "0.3.8"]
            [com.roomkey/lein-v "7.2.0"]]
  :parent-project {:path "../../project.clj"
                   :inherit [:managed-dependencies :repositories :manifest :url :prep-tasks]}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure]
                 [...]
                 [com.novemberain/pantomime "2.11.0" :exclusions 
                   [org.apache.commons/commons-compress
                    org.apache.pdfbox/fontbox
                    org.apache.tika/tika-parsers]]
                 [org.apache.tika/tika-parsers "1.27"]
                 
                 [com.sun.mail/javax.mail "1.6.2"]
                 [net.htmlparser.jericho/jericho-html "3.4"]
                 [org.simplejavamail/simple-java-mail "6.6.1"]
                 [org.simplejavamail/outlook-module "6.6.1"]]
   :profiles {:uberjar {:global-vars        {*warn-on-reflection* true}
                       :aot                :all
                       :omit-source        true
                       :uberjar-exclusions ["project.clj" #"xxx/.*\.clj$"]
                       :jvm-opts           ["-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow"]
                       :uberjar-name       "service.jar"}}
  :repl-options {:init-ns xxx.init})
```

#### affected code

```clj
(ns xxx.convert
  (:import (java.time OffsetDateTime ZoneOffset)
           (java.util Properties UUID Base64 Date)
           (java.io InputStream ByteArrayInputStream)
           (javax.activation MimeType)
           (javax.mail.internet MimeMessage MimeMultipart MimeBodyPart InternetAddress MimeUtility)
           (javax.mail Session Message Message$RecipientType)
           (net.htmlparser.jericho Source Renderer)
           (org.apache.commons.io IOUtils)

(defn- unpack-content [^Message message 
                       {:keys [max-text-length max-attachments] :as params}
                       counter]
  (log/debug "|> type" (type message))
  (when (or (not max-attachments)
            (< @counter max-attachments))
    (let [base-type (-> message .getContentType MimeType. .getBaseType string/lower-case)
          content   (.getContent message)] ;; <<< [!] This is where the conversion happens
      (log/debug "||>" (.toString ^MimeMultipart content))
      {:content-type base-type
       :content      (cond
                       (instance? String content)
                       (do
                         (log/trace "|-> transforming" base-type "to String")
                         (swap! counter inc)
                         (->> (if (html? base-type)
                                (render-html content)
                                content)
                              (truncate max-text-length)))

                       (and (instance? InputStream content)
                            (.getFileName message))
                       (let [filename     (MimeUtility/decodeText (.getFileName message))
                             encoded-file (do
                                            (swap! counter inc)
                                            (base64-file content filename))]
                         (log/trace "|-> transforming" base-type "to InputStream")
                         (.close ^InputStream content)
                         encoded-file)

                       (or (instance? MimeMessage content)
                           (instance? MimeMultipart content)
                           (instance? MimeBodyPart content))
                       (do
                         (log/debug "|-> transforming" base-type "to Mime for instance" (type content))
                         (unpack-mime content params counter))

                       :else
                       (do
                         (log/warn "Mime unpacking unsuccessful:" base-type "-" (type content))
                         {}))})))
```

Unfortunately I can't share the corresponding .doc file. However it is an official document with a common setup for plain mail with tables, images, etc.

**Why does it happen and how do I fix this?**

Comment: this is all guessing: having two classes on different packages is not a clash or a problem (it might be if some code tries smart things™). the switch from javax to jakarta is most likely done at some major version upstream and should not hit you. My guess here is rather, that you have deps, that maybe bring both in the same class - and you have different order of classpath at repl-time and run-time (via the generated uberjar). I'd check, if the files ending up in the uberjar are actually from the dep you are expecting. And still tripple check, if it's not just a fluke due to input...

Comment: How would I check such actual dependency?

Comment: If you want to rule out a clash either in classes or in META-INF, you could try to run the production code not as an uberjar but as a regular jar.  E.g. use `lein with-profile uberjar cp` to get all your libs. Then use those and your artifact (not the uberjar) and run this.  If this works again you can start to find the clash in your deps (or give up on uberjar)

Comment: Thanks so far @cfrick. I ran the artifact with `java -cp $(lein with-profile uberjar) xxx.init` and could reproduce the correct behaviour

Comment: Then my next guess would be something in META-INF. I know nothing about javax.mail, but usually those "old" libs allow for implementations to be configured via some factories/configs/properties/... - most likely at least two of your deps contain such files and the wrong one wins. If you can pin-point the problem, some libs also allow to setup via `-D` properties instead.

Comment: If there's anything we can do on the Apache Tika project to fix this, please open an issue on our JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/TIKA/summary

Comment: We "solved" the issue by using Tika 1.23. >1.24 had a similar behavior. Using 1.23 had little impact on the quality of our parsed documents.

Answer (score 2):

Leiningen has a well-known "feature"[1] regarding dependency order. Lein loads each dependency in order, recursively including all transitive dependencies. Imagine you have lein deps like:

```
[aaa/a "5.0"]
[bbb/b "5.0"]
```

However, `aaa/a` has a transitive dependency on `bbb/b` version `2.1`. Then Lein will bring in version `2.1` of `bbb/b` and ignore the explicit version you asked for.

The only way to combat this is to use a tiered listing of dependencies in `project.clj` like:

```
; priority 1 libs
[bbb/b  "5.0"]
[zzz/z  "10.3"]
...

; priority 2 libs
[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.3"]
[aaa/a "5.0"]
...
```

Which will force Lein to bring in the libs in the priority order you select.

Please try the above and report back with the results.  You may also need to print out the Classpath order from within the code to verify you are getting the order and version numbers you expect.

---

**Side note:**

I always recommend you add the `lein-ancient` plugin to your config like:

```
  :plugins [[com.jakemccrary/lein-test-refresh "0.24.1"]
            [lein-ancient "0.7.0"]
            ]
```

You can then define the alias:

```
lanc () {
    echo ""
    echo ""-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo "project.clj:"
    echo ""
    lein ancient check :all
    echo ""
    echo ""-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo "profiles.clj:"
    echo ""
    lein ancient check-profiles :all
    echo ""-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo ""
}
```

to identify which dependencies need upgrading. Note that both halves are important!

---

[1] Ancient computer joke:

```
  Q:  How do you recognize a computer salesman?
  A:  He says, "That's not a bug, that's a feature!"
```

Comment: Hi Alan, Thank you for your answer. I was aware of lein ancient, and in fact used it to upgrade dependencies. I did not know one could use `check-profiles :all` with it, but `lein ancient` and `lein ancient check :all` did not differ. I also tried to swap the order, but that unfortunately didn't change behaviour. I even tried to use different versions with the help of `lein ancient show-versions`. The problem apparently only occurs, when I pack an uberjar. Removing the artifact jar and running only the uberjar with its cp works without a flaw.

Answer (score 2):

The way the leiningen uberjar works, is basically by squashing all deps
into a single jar file.

This is no problem for most cases, due to clashes in the file structure
are very rare as java packages or clojure namespaces separate things.
There is of course the odd naming clash and sometimes libraries copy
things from different libraries for local adoptions (a good library
maintainer will "shadow" those copies so there is no chance for
a clash).

That said, there are files in jars, that are way more likely to clash:
things under `/META-INF/`.  In your case both `javax.mail` and
`jakarta.mail` are battling to be the provider for the mail interfaces
via `META-INF/services/javax.mail.Provider`.

If those files are loaded from the classpath there is the best case
scenario, that the libraries explicitly search for all such files and
have a resolve strategy in case of more than one result.  More likely,
libraries just let the class loader decide (most likely the first item
in CP, that contains the file, but this is of course an implementation
detail and you should not rely on it).  In that case you most likely
just where lucky while developing in your REPL and the correct one got
picked up.

Now if the uberjar squashes all those jars, the last file wins.  So
neither a resolve-strategy helps nor your "lucky first pick".  So what
can be done:

- get rid of one of the two deps.  Most likely you want to keep the
  `jakarta` ones, as the newer name suggests the newer library; this
  depends on the other libraries you are using, whether they can work
  with the new version and of course might need changes in your code
  too.
- don't roll an uberjar: I don't know of a plugin, that can give you
  something like the `application` plugin in gradle.  But you can get
  all the deps with `lein with-profile uberjar cp` and the non-uberjar
  artifact.  Then basically start with `java -cp libs/* my.main.ns`